# Azure Event hub cannot create topics for change data capture while integrating with kafka connect, debeizum connector and postgrsql

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-eventhub, debezium

I'm implementing a change data capture scenario using Azure Event Hub (kafka surface enabled), to capture data from postgresql. The database is Postgresql and uses the debizum connector  (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-postgres/1.2.0.Final/debezium-connector-postgres-1.2.0.Final-plugin.tar.gz). I also used azure postgres database (single server- logical replication) as well. The kafka connect runs on the docker locally, and can create topics in the azure event hubs (the docker compose file attached). Also once I send the rest request to the kafka connect, it shows the connector is up and running. However, when I insert data into the postgres table, it cannot create the topic in the eventhub, and I could not figure out the reason?

[Image of topics created for the kafka connect in eventhub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJnnF.png)

The status of connector:

```
localhost:8083/connectors/postgres-connector/status

{
    "name": "postgres-connector",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "connect:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "worker_id": "connect:8083"
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

This also looks weird to me that as soon as creating the source connector the kafka connect shows the following warning regarding connection to eventhub:

docker-file-connect-1   | [2022-09-22 08:24:11,152] INFO [Producer clientId=connector-producer-postgres-connector-0] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 32338 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 8ms, elapsed time since send: 8ms, request timeout: 30000ms) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
**docker-file-connect-1   | [2022-09-22 08:24:11,152] WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-postgres-connector-0] Bootstrap broker eventhubstandard.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)**

the post request for creating the connector:

```
localhost:8083/connectors

{
    "name": "postgres-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname": "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "todos-server",
        "plugin.name": "wal2json",
        "table.whitelist": "public.todos"
    }
}
```

the docker file used for connect and postgres

```
version: '2'
services:
  connect:
    image: mtpatter/debezium-connect  # built from debezium/connect:0.10 
    hostname: connect
    image: confluentinc/cp-server-connect-base:latest
    ports:
    - '8083:8083'
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'eventhubstandard.servicebus.windows.net:9093'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster

      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_config_topic
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_offset_topic
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect_status_topic
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      # Connect Worker
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "XXXXX"
      # Connect Producer
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "XXXXXX"
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "XXXXXXX"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "false"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "false"
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-sqlserver:latest
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql:latest
        #
        echo "launching kafka connector worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run &
        #
        sleep infinity
    volumes:
      - './kafka_connect:/connect'
```

Comment: You likely are missing `CONNECT_ADMIN_...` properties for SASL configuration. Otherwise, it'll fail connecting during topic-creation within the Connect API. That's also assuming EventHubs does support AdminClient Kafka API

Comment: @OneCricketeer not sure. needs to try this and see how it works

Comment: Otherwise, maybe it's just a general network error and your Azure VPC doesn't allow access from your machine... Have you tried using any other Kafka CLI commands to produce/consume?

Comment: Not sure if it is the network issue, as the kafka connect can create topics in azure eventhub, but debezium fails to do so, but worth to try. Thanks mate.

Comment: Debezium is only a plugin to Kafka Connect, so if Connect can, then Debezium can too, assuming you've provided the correct properties

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unrelated, but i would recommend using debezium server (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/operations/debezium-server.html#_azure_event_hubs). Connecting to events via kafka connect will cause you a bunch of headaches in the future.

Comment: I can with the kafka and debezium connector, the fact is how to utilise the eventhuub for this purpose. it reduce the need for cluster management as well and seems cheaper.

Comment: What do you mean by headaches? Debezium Server is just a wrapper around Connect

Comment: You dont need kafka connect when you are using Debezium Server.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-connect-tutorial

Anyways, my point is basically the warning on this page by microsoft themselves.

Comment: @user3518397 can you please share steps for connector config?